# AWS SQS each message allowed up to 254KB or the total data allowed in SQS is 254KB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

In AWS SQS is size of each message allowed up to 254KB or the total data allowed in SQS is 254KB,

how many meesages can be stored in SQS at any given time

Answer (score 1):

**Each** message can contain up to 256 KB of text in any format (still billed as four requests with 64KB chunks)

There is no limit on the number of messages.

Comment: Is there a limit on how many messages I can receive in terms of message size? or its only controlled by batchsize?

Comment: @Ajak6: There isn't a limit on the number of messages except for the max batch size of 10 and the throughput quota for FIFO queues. This doesn't apply on in-flight messages of course. See [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to the number of messages you can store in SQS, and the message size is 256K unless you are using the new Extended Client Library released in October 2015:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/10/now-send-payloads-up-to-2gb-with-amazon-sqs/

> Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) now has an Extended Client Library
>   that enables you to send and receive messages with payloads up to 2GB.
>   Previously, message payloads were limited to 256KB. Using the Extended
>   Client Library, message payloads larger than 256KB are stored in an
>   Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) bucket, using SQS to send and
>   receive a reference to the payload location.
>
> Large payload transmissions are billed as one SQS request and one S3 request, with
>   billing for the payload based on the amount of data stored in S3.